# Array search in PHP with duplicate value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$myFruit = 'apple';
$fruits = array( 
    '0' => array('banana', 'cherry'),
    '1' => array('apple', 'pear'),
    '2' => array('apple', 'kiwi')
);
```

I want to know in which array `apple` is.

So my code is the following and it's working.

```
foreach($fruits as $key => $fruit) {;
    if(in_array($myFruit, $fruit)) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

My problem is actually `apple` is in two arrays (`1` and `2`) and the code echoes `12` whereas it should stop when one result was found.

So it should echo `1` only and stop searching after.

How can I change my code for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use `break` statement after `echo $key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a break in your foreach to make it returns the first array where your word was found.

```
foreach($fruits as $key => $fruit) {;
   if(in_array($myFruit, $fruit)) {
       echo $key;
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: sure about this `$break` I don't think `break` is a variable. :)  it's a language construct...

Comment: You're right I add an "$" that it doesn't need, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a function, and a `return` statement in that function.

```
function search_subarray($haystacks, $needle) {
    foreach($haystacks as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($needle, $value)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

search_subarray($fruits, $fruit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using break statement will do the work.

You can read about it on official website [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

```
<?php

$myFruit = 'apple';
$fruits = array( 
    '0' => array('banana', 'cherry'),
    '1' => array('apple', 'pear'),
    '2' => array('apple', 'kiwi')
);

foreach($fruits as $key => $fruit) {;
    if(in_array($myFruit, $fruit)) {
        echo $key;
        break;// THIS WILL BREAK THE FOREACH LOOP
    }
}

?>
```